# Sending email once

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-automation, com-automation

For logging tasks I need to send me an email through Outlook. I wrote some code like this:

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$InboxDef = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)
$InboxDef.FullFolderPath -match "^\\\\(.*)\\Inbox$" | Out-Null
$recipient = $matches[1]
$email = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
$email.To = "$recipient"
$email.Subject = "Title"
$email.Body = "Text"
$email.Send()
$Outlook.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook) | Out-Null
```

When I subsequently launch the Outlook client I see the email sent twice

Comment: I tried your code and it sends the message once.  Is there some way that this could be called multiple times (e.g. is it in a loop, a function, etc)?  Do you get the problem if you run just this code separate to anything else?

Comment: This code is inserted into an if clause. Upstream such code I check if any Outlook client instance is active and I kill them in advance. The Oulook client is configured for multiple mail accounts, but I choose the default one (guessed from the GetDefaultFolder method)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good. One thing which is not clear enough is setting a recipient for the outgoing email:

```
$InboxDef.FullFolderPath -match "^\\\\(.*)\\Inbox$" | Out-Null
$recipient = $matches[1]
```

It is not clear what value is used in the code. To make sure the property is set correctly I'd suggest using the `Recipients` property of the `MailItem` class instead. The [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection. Then don't forget to use the [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve)
method which attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book.

Read more about that in the article which I wrote for the technical blog, see  [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/).

Comment: See my comment in the original post